# Access SQL statement to query the current day

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with an access database for school and I'm trying to figure out how to pull all of the transactions from the current day without having to manually change the date range. My current query is:

```
SELECT COUNT (CustID) AS [Number of Transactions]
FROM [Transaction]
WHERE Date=_____
```

So is there a way to have access pull the date from the machine and use that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Getdate() equivalent in access is Now().

if you format the date column as a short date, then format now as a short date, they will be equivalent.

```
    SELECT COUNT (CustID) AS [Number of Transactions]
    FROM [Transaction]
    WHERE format (date, "short date") = format(now(), "short date")
```

Comment: Adding the Date() in the WHERE statement returns every transaction to date- is there a way to only get the transactions from today?

Comment: what is the name of your date column? replace that with date

Comment: You saved the day! FYI my trans table has a "Date" column which was set as a text field so I changed that to date/time and then used the short date in the format line.

Answer (score 1):

Use date() function in your where clause. That will give you the current date results. i.e.
Where [Date] = date()

Comment: @Zach, you should have enough rep now to upvote the answers you like and that help you. Get to it. :)

Comment: Haha I took care of it